# Java array type declaration

Tags: java, arrays, types, declaration

For the following line of code:

```
int x [ ] = new int [5]
```

Why is the second `int` necessary? Is the second type-declaration not always the same as the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this specific case it may seem verbose and redundant, but since we're dealing with OO language, it's very likely (and useful) to run into declarations like:

```
Shape shape = new Triangle(); //where Triangle implements Shape interface
```

Same reason goes here, an Array could be of general type and contain items of different types, or, different type of arrays (that extend the same type). For example:

```
Number[] tmpNumbersArray = new Integer[10]; //
```

Answer (score 1):

No, of cause.

```
Number [] numbers = new Float[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you have the values at compile time:

```
int[] x = {34, 45, 78};
```

Also look at this:

**Declaration with data type**

```
int[] a,b = new int[3]; //multiple arrays declared
```

**Declaration with variable**

```
int a[], b;//multiple declaration, but not all are arrays
a = new int[3];//later you can define the array size
```